# Sending POST request with JSON data in DJANGO and response from view also JSON data but its giving 403 FORBIDDEN error

Tags: python, json, django

I am trying to send a POST request to Django with JSON data in it and the view is returning response with JSON data. But when I send a request to it, it returns with `403 Forbidden` error. I am using `RESTClient` to send/test POST requests.

I have read all about CSRF in documentation but its not very helpful. I am fairly new to Django and the other questions posted here are not helping me a lot.

The code in my view is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse;
import json;
def index(request):
        if request.is_ajax():
            if request.method == 'POST':
                print 'Raw Data: "%s"' % request.body;
                reply = json.loads(request.body);
                return HttpResponse(reply);
            else:
                return HttpResponse("OK");

        else:
            return HttpResponse("OK");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @ArpitGoyal's answer you can also decorate your view with [`csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt):

> This decorator marks a view as being exempt from the protection ensured by the middleware.

A few tips in case you do need CSRF protection:

1. Check CSRF token cookie name.

   See [`CSRF_COOKIE_NAME`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-name) for more information.
2. Add [`ensure_csrf_cookie`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie) decorator to your view.

   According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax):

   > **Warning**
   >
   > If your view is not rendering a template containing the [`csrf_token`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-csrf_token) template tag, Django might not set the CSRF token cookie. This is common in cases where forms are dynamically added to the page. To address this case, Django provides a view decorator which forces setting of the cookie: [`ensure_csrf_cookie()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie).
3. Assuming that CSRF token cookie name is `csrftoken`, try to send `X-CSRFToken` header.

   ```
   $.ajax({
       // Your options here.
       headers: {'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')}
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You should authenticate your client before making the request. From your call you are providing a ajax `POST` request hit.

Provide a `header` in your `RESTClient`: `X-CSRFToken`.

For more details view [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/)

Comment: Suppose I use RESTClient of FireFox to test the service, what should I exactly add to the header ?